# Combine list of data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, list, merge

I have a list of data frames in R

Each data frame's rownames are dates and they have a column named number.

I want to create a single data frame from the list such that the columnames are the same as list element names

Eg,
if

```
    df1 <- data.frame( number = c(10, 20, 30))
    rownames(df1) <- c("202201", "202202", "202203")

    df2 <- data.frame( number = c(20, 30, 30))
    rownames(df2) <- c("202201", "202202", "202203")

    df <- list(A = df1, B = df2)
```

I want to combine df such that result is

```
       | A        |  B       |       
  
202201 | 10       | 20       |
202202 | 20       | 30       |
202203 | 30       | 30       |
```

The actual data contains multiple data frames and the range of date, i.e the rownames may also differ.

I would prefer a full join

I tried using the following method

```
merged_df <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 0, all = TRUE), df)
```

I got the warning

```
"In merge.data.frame() column names are dupicated in the result "
```

The output contains `multiple columns with row.names and number.x , number.y`

Comment: Your expected output has nothing from `df2`, please explain why the result should be effectively `df[[1]]` only. I don't get that warning/error, btw, it returns a 3-column frame with names `c("Row.names", "number.x", "number.y")`

Comment: Also, you "name" the first frame `name1`, it seems like you want this new column to take on the `Row.names` provided by `merge`, but `name2` is then assigned to the `number` of the second (and subsequent) frame? Both the merge logic and the naming logic are unclear to me, can you help me to better understand?

Comment: There was a typing error which I corrected.  Now you would be able to understnading th emerge logic better. I have chnaged the names also for you to better understand the naming logic.

Comment: I think the desired output changed!

Comment: I really appreciate that you provided a simple dataset with simple code to demonstrate your point. However, when you do so you really need to verify that the fake data and code you provide actually reproduces the behavior with which you're having trouble. In this case, it is not. I think I figured out that the problem is having 3 or more frames in your `df` list, but if not then ***it is on you*** to make sure that the data you provide does what you say it does. There are several answers here that will not remove that warning.

Comment: Is there any way I can change the column names in merge function ?

Comment: yes you can. Simply use `setNames(Reduce(\(x,y)data.frame(merge(x,y, by=0, all =TRUE),row.names = 1), df), names(df))`

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right start:

```r
# unchanged
out <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 0, all = TRUE), df)
# remove `Row.names` column
rownames(out) <- out[[1]]
# change all remaining names
out <- setNames(out[,-1], names(df))
out
#         A  B
# 202201 10 20
# 202202 20 30
# 202203 30 30
```

But I don't get your error, even without the new code. I suspect that having more in the `df` list is causing some problem.

```r
df3 <- data.frame(number = c(20, 40, 60))
rownames(df3) <- c("202201", "202202", "202204")
df <- list(A = df1, B = df2, C = df3)
out <- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = 0, all = TRUE), df)
# Warning in merge.data.frame(x, y, by = 0, all = TRUE) :
#   column name ‘Row.names’ is duplicated in the result
```

This is because the first merge results in a frame without row names, so therefore the magic of `by=0` (or `by="row.names"`) can no longer work.

```r
merge(df1, df2, by=0, all=T)
#   Row.names number.x number.y
# 1    202201       10       20
# 2    202202       20       30
# 3    202203       30       30
#### note: no row names, additional column
```

We have two options:

1. Pre-shift all frames to have the row-names as a real column. (*Personally* I prefer the first step here, since I don't trust row-names and either ignore or actively remove them from my data. `dplyr` and similar packages often removes them as well, fyi, in case you're thinking of using anything from the tidyverse. But I'll continue without that preference.)

   ```r
   out <- lapply(df, function(obj) transform(obj, rowname = rownames(obj))) |>
     Reduce(f = function(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "rowname", all = TRUE))
   out
   #   rowname number.x number.y number
   # 1  202201       10       20     20
   # 2  202202       20       30     40
   # 3  202203       30       30     NA
   # 4  202204       NA       NA     60
   ```

   which looks more reasonable. From here, the same cleanup as above will restore the row-names as you want.

   ```r
   rownames(out) <- out[[1]]
   out <- setNames(out[,-1], names(df))
   out
   #         A  B  C
   # 202201 10 20 20
   # 202202 20 30 40
   # 202203 30 30 NA
   # 202204 NA NA 60
   ```
2. Shift the new `Row.names` column back to be row-names, internally.

   ```r
   out <- Reduce(function(x, y) {
     out <- merge(x, y, by = 0, all = TRUE)
     rownames(out) <- out$Row.names
     out[,-1]
   }, df)
   names(out) <- names(df)
   out
   #         A  B  C
   # 202201 10 20 20
   # 202202 20 30 40
   # 202203 30 30 NA
   # 202204 NA NA 60
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Using `base`, I'd name the columns first using a simple loop, and then call `merge` in a `Reduce()`.

However, when you `merge` based on row names, `merge` turns the row names into a column. Because of this, the merging 2 data frames by row names works just fine, but if we try to add a 3rd there is an issue because the result of the first merge doesn't have row names any more. To solve this, we'll convert the row names to a column in all the data frames before merging, then convert back at the end.

```
## make the example a tiny bit more complicated
## to make sure the row names are not an issue
## (thanks to @r2evans)
df3 <- data.frame(number = c(20, 40, 60))
rownames(df3) <- c("202201", "202202", "202204")
df <- list(A = df1, B = df2, C = df3)

# make the column names same as list names
# and add row names as an actual column
for(i in seq_along(df)) {
  names(df[[i]]) = names(df)[i]
  df[[i]]$merge_id = row.names(df[[i]])
}

# merge by our ID
result = Reduce(\(x, y) merge(x, y, by = "merge_id", all = TRUE), df)
# convert back to row_names
row.names(result) = result$merge_id
result$merge_id = NULL
result
#         A  B  C
# 202201 10 20 20
# 202202 20 30 40
# 202203 30 30 NA
# 202204 NA NA 60
```

Comment: I don't think this is meeting the under-stated problem in the OP, namely this does not resolve an error when `length(df)` is longer than 2. Perhaps try with the length-3 `df` in my answer? I wonder if this simple base-R method can be adapted to work with the second+ merge.

Comment: Ah, because `merge` converts the row names to a column. I'll address that, thanks!

Comment: `setNames(Reduce(\(x,y)data.frame(merge(x,y, by=0, all =TRUE),row.names = 1), df), names(df))` should solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tidyverse option:

```r
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

imap(df, ~ mutate(.x, rn = row.names(.x), "{.y}" := number, .keep = "none")) |>
  reduce(full_join, by = "rn")
#       rn  A  B
# 1 202201 10 20
# 2 202202 20 30
# 3 202203 30 30
```

Using `imap` and a formula (e.g. `~`), as you iterate through your list of data frames you can access the current iteration element with `.x` and the current iteration name with `.y`.

Using `.x` and `.y`, you can pull the row names into a column and rename `number` using [glue-style syntax](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/glue-operators.html). Then join all elements of the list together with `reduce`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** With the new desired output:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(powerjoin)

map(df,~(.x %>%rownames_to_column("name1"))) %>% 
  power_full_join(., by = "name1") 

  name1 number.x number.y
1 202201       10       20
2 202202       20       30
3 202203       30       30
```

**First answer:**
Here is a way using the `powerjoin` package:

If you want to keep the list structure, we can do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
library(powerjoin)

map(df,~(.x %>%rownames_to_column("name1"))) %>% 
  power_left_join(., by = c("name1", "number")) %>% 
  rename(name2 = number)
```

```
 name1 name2
1 202201    10
2 202202    20
3 202203    30
```

Answer (score -1):

do.call(cbind, df)

```
       number number
202201     10     20
202202     20     30
202203     30     30
```

Comment: No, the OP said *"the rownames may also differ"*, where this will not work correctly. For instance, try `rownames(df[[1]])[3] <- "202204"; do.call(cbind, df)` to see that it mis-correlates the third-row of each.

Comment: you rigth. Thanks for pointing it out